# Can't set tables to be centered and aligned in different sections

Tags: html, css, html-table, center

I have an invoice to be displayed as HTML.
I'm tranforming an XML to HTML via XSLT and I have basically:

- 4 tables that I need to display on 2 different sections, one above the other
- each section has 2 tables, they should be centered covering the most of the page
- tables should be also vertically aligned so that tables in different sections are on the same vertical position.

My first problem is that I can't make the third table go in a different section, I would see all tables in the same line even though I'm using div to separate them.

Here below is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
<!-- CSS goes in the document HEAD or added to your external stylesheet -->
<style type="text/css">
.zui-table {
    border: solid 1px #DDEEEE;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
    font: normal 16px Arial, sans-serif;
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
    float:left;

#top
{
    width: 100%; /* si adatta in larghezza a alle 
                    risoluzioni di tutti i browser */
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
h1 {
        position: relative;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-family:Mistral;
        margin-top: 0;
        color: #b34d4d;
    }

</style>

</head>
   <body>

      <div id="top"><h1><center>TEST CBF INVOICE</center></h1></div>

      <div align="center">
      <table class="zui-table zui-table-rounded"> 
         <th colspan="2" class="zui-table thead th">INVOICE DETAILS</th>
         <xsl:for-each select="//B0100_invoice_number_block">
            <xsl:if test="position() = 2">

            <tr>
               <td>BILL ID</td>
               <td><xsl:value-of select="D0101" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>START INVOICE PERIOD</td>
               <td><xsl:value-of select="D0102" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>END INVOICE PERIOD</td>
               <td><xsl:value-of select="D0103" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>INVOICE DATE</td>
               <td><xsl:value-of select="D0104" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>DUE DATE</td>
               <td><xsl:value-of select="D0105" /></td>
            </tr>
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
       </table>
       <table class="zui-table zui-table-rounded">
        <tr>
           <th>ACCOUNT DETAILS</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="//B0600_mobile_number_block">
        <xsl:if test="position() = 2">

        <tr>
          <td>ACCOUNT ID</td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="subs_id"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>MSISDN</td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="D0601_MSISDN"/></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </table>         
        </div>

        <div>
        <table class="zui-table zui-table-rounded">
        <tr>
           <th>ACCOUNT Invoice Summary</th>
        </tr>

        <xsl:for-each select="//B09001/details">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="descr_en"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Amt"/></td>
        </tr>

         </xsl:for-each>
         <xsl:for-each select="//B09002/details">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="descr_en"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Amt"/></td>
        </tr>
         </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
        <table class="zui-table zui-table-rounded">
        <tr>
           <th>Subscriber Invoice Summary</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="//BS09001/details">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="descr_en"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Amt"/></td>
        </tr>
         </xsl:for-each>
         <xsl:for-each select="//BS09002/details">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="descr_en"/></td>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="Amt"/></td>
        </tr>
         </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `float: left` makes it so that they are all in the same line. 
you have to align the div that contain the tables and not the tables itself. Also the div with `align=center` is only on 1 of the tables.
Both sections should be wrapped in a div and those divs hould be wrapped in a centered div.

I made a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ncsqhx9f/).

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
```

instead of `float:left`;

Check https://jsfiddle.net/0k8zgteu/